# Why is the HTC Legend Froyo ROM labelled as being for Vodafone?

Tags: rom, htc-legend

I am currently using Optus and would like to upgrade to this [ROM](http://www.htc.com/au/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=1074&news_id=852), but it is labelled as being a Vodafone ROM. Is this important? Is the ROM locked to the network or are there other issues it may cause if I installed it. Would this be any different from buying a phone from Vodafone then switching networks?

Comment: Where do you live and what carrier handles your cell service?

Comment: @JonnyP: Australia and using Optus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done sort of the reverse -- installed a US T-Mobile ROM to my T-Mobile phone while I had it on the Canadian Rogers network.  Since the Legend is also a GSM phone like my Vibrant, I would expect yours to work just as well as mine did.  Just make sure you have your SIM card in for the whole process.

Comment: "and if you back up your apps/settings (e.g. with Titanium Backup) don't restore any data for the system apps, which might overwrite your current network's data with Vodafone data." If I backup, then install a Vodafone ROM, then restore, wouldn't my Optus settings be saved?

Comment: Good point, I was thinking too much about my case, where I switched carriers and ROMs at the same time.